# Raspberry Pi 0 W spontaneous event triggering for an input pin

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have two "Cylewet 25Pcs AC 1A 125V 3Pin SPDT Limit Micro Switch"-es that are normally open and connected to two of the Pi pins with internal pull up resistors.
Left unattended, they call spontaneously the registered function as though they were pressed. What could be the reason for that?
Here is the important part of the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def func(channel: int):
    ...
    log.debug('The end breaker is pressed - channel %i', channel)

GPIO.setup([18,19], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.FALLING, callback=func)
GPIO.add_event_detect(19, GPIO.FALLING, callback=func)
```

Here is the log:

```
2019-10-26 14:10:03,982 INFO     last activity
2019-10-26 16:46:21,676 DEBUG    module(func[xxx]): The end breaker is pressed - channel 18
2019-10-26 16:46:21,681 DEBUG    module(func[xxx]): The end breaker is pressed - channel 18
2019-10-26 16:46:21,688 DEBUG    module(func[xxx]): The end breaker is pressed - channel 19
```

Comment: Hi Plamen, this question is off topic for Super User. You should post this on the [Rasberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I will post there, this place was referred to me by stackoverflow.

Comment: Strange. This is more on topic for StackOverflow than it is for Super User